# How to firewall Windows IP Forwarding

Tags: windows, networking, routing, firewall

Looking into using a Windows 10 machine as a VPN gateway for a network, using IP Forwarding to make Windows 10 route packets between the Ethernet interface and a VPN interface.

I can foresee needing to firewall this routing between the LAN and the VPN, for example to allow VPN clients access to only specific resources on the LAN.

However i don't know how best to setup Windows 10's firewall with rules to control the forwarding/routing of packets. Of course i am familiar with firewall's in general, but rather inexperienced at using the built-in Windows offering.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: `i am familiar with firewall's in general, but rather inexperienced at using the built-in Windows offering` - why don't you use what you know, rather than using an operating system that was probably never designed to do what you want easily

Comment: Because i am specifically looking to use the Windows 10 server that i already have setup for this task - Besides, it is a good opportunity to learn about the Windows firewall.

Comment: Fair enough, just asking. Windows firewall is absolute garbage to work with if you want to do anything other than block incoming or outgoing traffic

Comment: Ah - I wondered. Is what i am aiming for even possible?